# How to push selective fields from the key and value from Topic1 to Topic2 using kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using KStream and would like to extract and push only a subset of the fields from the key and value from Topic1 to Topic2.

For ex, if my value in message contains fields like id, name, address, phoneno... i would like to push only id, name and address to a new topic. This is similar to replacefield.whitelist transform, but i would like to try with KStream.

I am able to do this for a single field, but not sure how to prepare the new value for multiple fields (resulting in a GenericRecord).

Comment: Please share what you've tried as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use the `KStream.map` function to get access to both the key and value then you'd return a new key value pair.

```java
stream.map((k, v) -> {
    GenericRecord r = new GenericData.Record();  // needs a schema 
    r.put("name", v.getName());  // for example 
    return new KeyValue(k, r);
}).to("topic2")
```

If not using Avro Serde, or other generic type, you'd also need to define your own serde class.

Comment: Following your code as is, it throws an error at `GenericRecord r = new GenericRecord();` as **'GenericRecord' is abstract; cannot be instantiated**. How to workaround this ?

Comment: Ah,sorry. It was just an example, but try making a `GenericData.Record`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, had to pass schema as well along with it else it does not work, was able to manage that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction to get started.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Avro objects would already have a schema, so you shouldn't need to pass that along separately. But for making a new Avro object, yes, that makes sense

Comment: Yup, since i am creating a new AVRO object with a new schema, i needed to do that. Thanks for your help.